# How to Keep the same Transaction open, between page requests in Webforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, request

I'm trying to persist a transaction in a webform page as the page takes user input and adds this to a transaction, however I can't get the data to insert on the transaction commit command. I want to know how to be able to use the same transaction between requests and gradually add data into the transaction before committing:

Sample code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope transactionScope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {

        switch (Request["Mode"])
        {
            // Start of transaction
            case "QueryProcess":

                var dataSetID = Request["hdnDataSetID"].ToNullableInt();

                var queryObjectItem = dbLinq.QueryObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QueryObjectID == dataSetID);

                if (queryObjectItem == null)
                {
                    queryObjectItem = new QueryObject();
                    queryObjectItem.ObjectType = "DATASETTest";
                    queryObjectItem.ObjectID = (int)dataSetID;
                    context.QueryObjects.InsertOnSubmit(queryObjectItem);

                    context.SubmitChanges();

                    SendAjaxResponse(AjaxResponseStateEnum.OK, new
                    {
                        QueryObject = queryObjectItem,
                        IsExisting = false
                    });
                }

                else if (queryObjectItem != null)
                {
                    // Set the label for the current query object

                    SendAjaxResponse(AjaxResponseStateEnum.OK, new
                    {
                        QueryObject = queryObjectItem,
                        IsExisting = true,
                        QueryObjectLabelText = "Viewing QueryObject with ID of " + queryObjectItem.QueryObjectID
                    });
                }

                break;

            // This binds the fields or dropdownsd 
            case "Tables.InitialModalBind":

                using (context.Transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                {
                    var queryObjectItem = new QueryObject();
                    queryObjectItem.ObjectType = "DATASETTest";
                    queryObjectItem.ObjectID = (int)12456;
                    context.QueryObjects.InsertOnSubmit(queryObjectItem);

                    context.SubmitChanges();

                    context.Transaction.Commit();

                    break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I see no SQL there. Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: The transaction is communicating with a SQL database.

Comment: Which SQL database? MS SQL Server or other?

Comment: MS SQL database

Comment: SQL is a language, supported by many different products. MS SQL Server is one of them. Since this question isn't about the SQL language, I removed the <sql> tag and instead added the <sql-server> tag.

Comment: You do **NOT** want to do this. Maintaining a transaction across multiple page requests is an extremely bad idea. You will cause all sorts of problems. What happens when a user starts adding or editing data on the first page. Then they go to page two and get distracted for 20 minutes? Your web session times out and your transaction is left hanging. This is a recipe for disaster. You need to rethink how to handle this. If you want to capture data across multiple pages you need to use caching or the session.